# List approval flow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, splistitem

I have a SharePoint list. When we fill out the details there are two things which we ask

1. Department Review and Approval
2. Assign To

Once we save the form, the `Department Review and Approval` should receive an email to approve the form. is there a way we can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is sevral solution.

- You can add a Approval SharePoint 2010 Workflow on Your list. (You need to enable the feature Workflow).And Configure your approval workflow.  [Understand approval workflows](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Understand-approval-workflows-in-SharePoint-2010-a24bcd14-0e3c-4449-b936-267d6c478579)

OR

- You can Enable the Content Approval on you list. and give the Approval Permission to your member who are allowed to Approve item. (You can set Alert on your list to send Email when a item is created)

Comment: But this will send email to all the users on the approval list. But what i am trying to do is... I have 5 users who has to approve and only one person should receive the email who is being selected on the department review. Eg: Department review has manager named sam, nick, john, chris, bob. If I select sam then sam should receive email, if i select john then only john should receive email and not all of them. Please advise

Comment: There is a solution but ugly. You create an AD group, you put your users in this AD group. You ADD the Approval Workflow on your list (start when item is created). You set the field Approvers (in the init Forms of Workflow)with your AD Group. When user create a doc, the init form appear and the user set the field CC with the user who should receive Email.

Comment: The OOTD workflow always send email to approvers. When we pass by an AD group, Sharepoint can't retreive the Email. So Approvers will never receive Email, only the CC. IF this solution is not good, you must go through Custom Worklfow (with SharePoint Designer, Or Visual Studio)

Comment: thanks I will look into the possibility which will be suitable. Thanks for prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a task list. In the Advanced settings, do 2 things:

1. Turn on the management of content types
2. Turn on E-Mail Notification

Hide the unnecessary filed from the content type you don't need.

Then, when an item is created, it will email the designated Assigned To user(s).